# Under what circumstances is the action of conjugation by an element $g$ on a group $G$ transitive?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

My question is as seen in the title. I thought to use the orbit-stablilizer theorem but am not sure if perhaps I've only obtained a sufficient condition. My question is what are the necessary and sufficient conditions for the conjugation action $\psi: G \to$ Aut($G$) defined by $\psi(g) = C_g$ to be transitive?

My attempt is as below:

> By the OST, conjugation is transitive if and only if the factor group $G/G_x$ is of the same size (exists a bijection) with $G$ (since $G = Gg$ for any $g \in G$ in a transitive action). Thus there must be as many distinct cosets in $G/G_x$ as elements in $G$. That is, each coset must be of size 1. By the proof of Lagrange's theorem, we know that this means that the subgroup part of each coset, $G_x$, is of size 1 and, since $e \in G_x$, we have $G_x = \{e\}$.

But is this a characterization? Can I go further? I also don't think this result is right seeing as I would've expected there to be just one coset (intuitively based on the idea that a transitive action lets us "reach" any element from any other).

Comment: The answer is $|G|=1$.

Comment: Can you provide a hint? I can only see that "Thus there must be as many distinct cosets as elements in $G$", but no further. @DerekHolt

Comment: Central conjugacy classes are singletons, so there is one orbit (=conjugacy class), only, iff $G=Z(G)=\{e\}$.

Comment: @orione Can you help me see that based on what I've written? I've only found that the isotropy/stabilizer group for each $x$ is a singleton, but can't see how that yields your statement.

Comment: The stabilizer is here the centralizer, which comprises al least $e$ and $x$, by definition. Therefore, it is trivial (for [sub]groups this is more suitable than "singleton", which best suits for [sub]sets) iff $x=e$.

Comment: @orione I'm still not sure I follow. If you are able, I would greatly appreciate you fleshing out your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have  proved that $G_x=\{e\}$. But, by definition, $G_x=\{g\in G\mid gxg^{-1}=x\}$, whence $x\in G_x$ (in fact, $xxx^{-1}=x$). Therefore, $x=e$. But this all holds for every $x\in G$, and hence $G=\{e\}$. Namely, for *nontrivial* $G$, the action of $G$ on itself by conjugation is never transitive.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think to directly use the definition of $G_x$ and therefore missed what you were saying. Thank you so much!